# Use of "past-dweller"

Tags: word-in-context

Is the use of the expression "past-dweller" correct in the phrases below:

> Please, don't take me for a **past-dweller**. Some of today's songs are
>   great, and I like them, but none of them are as good as the ones we
>   had in the sixties and seventies.

and

> Your days of fame and glory are gone. You must stop being a
>   **past-dweller**, get yourself a real job, and start living life as an
>   ordinary person, just like everybody else in the family.

Is this expression commonly used in English?
Are there any alternatives that would sound more colloquial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't *think* I've ever seen the hyphenated "past-dweller" before, so I would have to answer your question of usage by saying it is *not* common. However, it is immediately obvious to a native speaker that it must mean *one who dwells in the past*, just as a "pond-dweller" would be a creature that dwells or lives in a pond. "Dwelling (or living) in the past" *is* a common phrase which means *having old-fashioned or outdated ideas and attitudes*, so while the term "past-dweller" isn't commonly used it is directly alluding to a common expression.

English allows for creativity in the use of both *hyphenated* and *compound words*. It is quite common for a product name to be created as a compound word and it should be easily understood by native speakers that it does what its name implies. For example, it seems obvious that a "dustbuster" gets rid of dust.

There are lots of synonyms to describe a *thing* which is "old fashioned", such as "antiquated", "outmoded" etc. The words I can think of to describe a *person* who is stuck in the past vary in meaning:

- Traditionalist - an advocate of maintaining tradition, especially so as to resist change
- Nostalgic - Someone who enjoys things from the past, not necessarily someone who resists them
- Luddite - someone who actively refuses to embrace new technologies
- Anachronistic - Someone or something that belongs to an earlier time period
- Fuddy Duddy - a person who is very old-fashioned and pompous.

If any of these, "nostalgic" could replace the term "past-dweller" in your sentence and is probably the most widely used, but it would not necessarily carry the same meaning.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for all the explanations and alternatives you provided. I saw this expression in the movie "Everybody wants to be Italian" where there is the following dialog: You're a past-dweller / Fine, if holding into memories makes me a past-dweller, then I'm a past-dweller. Once again, thanks for your help.